# Unable to delete .exe file through c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an update button within the windows form application.When the user clicks on the update button, the application checks the current version of the application with the version available in the server obtained from the webservice. If there is mismatch among versions,the application will download the new version from the path obtained from the webservice.

I am currently using two projects within the same solution

1. Main project where the application is running
2. Update project -Its purpose is used to delete the .exe file and download the new .exe file. (Update project is added as a reference of Main project)

The problem is when i try to delete the mainproject.exe through code in update project,it shows an exception saying "Unauthorized exception caught". Does anyone knows why this is happening?OR Does anyone have a better idea to use update function within the application??

This is the code that i am using for the deleting the file.

[Unauthorized Exception in Windows Forms - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305475/unauthorized-exception-in-windows-forms-c-sharp)

**Edit:-**

While i was debugging the application,iam able to delete the .exe file.But when i try to delete the application after installing in the desktop,again iam getting the exception message as "Access is denied".

Comment: Why not downloading the update.exe first then run it before closing the current running instance, then the update.exe will check and delete the mainproject.exe

Comment: @KingKing :Let me try this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution why iam getting the "access is denied" exception in my application.

Since iam deleting a file inside the application through code i need to have the privilege of "Administrator".

One way is to make the user login manually as administrator.But that is not a better option.

Another way is to create an App Manifest file within your project and set the level as "administartor."

**Creating App Manifest--> Right click on the project->Add new item-->Select App Manifest option from the right pane->Click ok**

Open the manifest file and change the level to "requireAdministartor".

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This will solve the issue while running the application,it will prompt user to run as administrator.

Hope this will be helpful to someone in future. :) Thank you guys for your support.

Comment: Be sure to only do this for the *update* application. There's a good reason Windows switched to not running the user applications using administrator privileges (which includes changing anything inside Program files, which is why your updater failed). And please, do use a self-signed certificate to make sure the updater and the updated exes and dlls you downloaded is actually made by you and not modified by anyone else (SNK is quite enough, but you *have* to check it manually; or at least, use HTTPS to do the downloads). I've seen auto updaters download viruses so often it's not funny anymore.

Answer (score 4):

In you update button, you start another small app as a separate process , in the small app, you can use the following code to kill your process, and then delete the original app.

```
try
{
    Process [] proc Process.GetProcessesByName("YourAppName");
    proc[0].Kill();
}
```

Comment: Ohh...you are right.I was actually killing the application after starting the small app within the first project.I should have done the above process in the small app..Really helped me.Thank you.. :)

Comment: Iam unable to delete the application after installing in the desktop.But was able to delete the .exe while debugging the application

Comment: @Mothy, Would you check your process is still running while you try to delete it.  Use Task Manager can see. You can do something interesting, for example, stop the process in your small app, sleep 5 seconds, during that time, you can check Task Manager whether the process is still running. If the process is still running, manually kill it. See whether your small app can delete it or not. Just try to separate which part causes the problem.

Comment: No the process is not running in the task manger.I have checked that.

Comment: What's the error? "Access is denied"? Did you log the exception in file? Is it possible a privilege issue? Running in Administrator mode?

Comment: Please find the answer that i have added below.That resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Is the application running and that's why it is unable to delete the executable? If so, you could rename the running executable and put the new version in its place. The new version will then be executed the next time the application is started.

Comment: You may be right the application may be running.If the application is running will i be able to rename the application??

Comment: @Mothy, no. You can't rename a file that is locked by a process, be it an exe or a data file. You need to completely close your main app before running the update.

Comment: @gunr2171 :  If i close my main application using "Application.Exit()"..will i be able to sponge the update application through the "Process" ??

Comment: Actually, you can rename a running executable.