# Access is denied in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

Iam asking this question as a series to  the below link

[Unable to delete .exe file through c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325805/unable-to-delete-exe-file-through-c-sharp)

While i was debugging the application,iam able to delete the .exe file.But when i try to delete the application after installing in the desktop,again iam getting the exception message as "Access is denied".

**Edit:-**

The code i am using to delete the file

```
    public bool deleteAppExecutable(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {

            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {

                var di = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
                di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
                SetAccessRule(filePath);
                File.SetAttributes(filePath, File.GetAttributes(filePath) & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
                File.Delete(filePath);

            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           return false;
        }
    }


    public static void SetAccessRule(string filePath)
    {

        FileInfo dInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);

        FileSecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();


        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.Delete, AccessControlType.Allow));
        dInfo.Refresh();
        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution why i am getting the "access is denied" exception in my application.

Since i am deleting a file inside the application through code i need to have the privilege of "Administrator".

One way is to make the user login manually as administrator.But that is not a better option.

Another way is to create an App Manifest file within your project and set the level as "administrator."

**Creating App Manifest--> Right click on the project->Add new item-->Select App Manifest option from the right pane->Click ok**

Open the manifest file and change the level to "requireAdministartor".

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This will solve the issue while running the application,it will prompt user to run as administrator.

Hope this will be helpful to someone in future. :)

Answer (score -1):

Check that you have full permissions on the folder the exe is contained in (and all of it's child objects)

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to comment below their post.